# Visual representation of $\textrm{Re}(kz+m)>0$, with $k,m,z$ complex?

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers

Suppose $k,m$ are fixed complex numbers. I need to geometrically describe the set of all points $z$ with $\textrm{Re}(kz+m)>0$.

My approach was to let $k=k_x+ik_y$, $m=m_x+im_y$, $z=z_x+iz_y$. Then, we obtain

$kz+m=(k_x+ik_y)(z_x+iz_y)+m_x+im_y$

$=k_xz_x-k_yz_y+m_x+i(k_yz_x+k_xz_y+m_y)$.

Therefore, $\textrm{Re}(kz+m)=k_xz_x-k_yz_y+m_x$, which gives

$z\in\{z=z_x+iz_y\mid k_xz_x-k_yz_y+m_x>0\}$.

However, I'm confused as to how to come up with a geometric representation of this set.

Comment: Easier to think of $k$ as $k=re^{i\theta}$, perhaps. Then you have a composition of rotation, dilation, and translation. Very easy to understand geometrically.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't thought about using polar but it definitely makes the geometric representation much easier to visualize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $k$ in polar form, $k=re^{i\theta}$.  Starting with any $z$, we find $kz+m$ geometrically by

- multiplying the modulus of $z$ by the real factor $r$;
- rotating through an angle $\theta$ anticlockwise;
- translating (shifting) by the complex number $m$.

In your set the result of all these transformations is the right half-plane.  So to find where $z$ lies you must reverse all the above operations:

- $kz$ is located in the half-plane with vertical boundary passing through the point $-m$;
- $rz$ is located in this half-plane rotated by an angle $\theta$ clockwise;
- $z$ is located in the previous half-plane with all distances from $0$ divided by $r$.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the line (in the complex plane) 
$$k_x z_x - k_y z_y = -m_x$$
So for instance, if $k_x = 2$ and $k_y = 5$ and $m_x = 7$ draw the line $2x-5y = -7$.

The region that satisfies the inequality is half the plane, bounded by that line (which is outside the region). Which side of the line? Well, you want $k_x x +-k_y y > -m$. Now if $k_y > 0$, then as $y$ gets more positive, the left hand side gets more negative, and you eventually violate the inequality; therefore, if $k_y > 0$ the region is the lower of the two regions.  Similarly, if $k_y < 0$ the inequality is satisfied in the upper of the two regions.

And if $k_y = 0$ then you need the right side of the line if $k_x > 0$, or the left side if $k_x < 0$.

Finally, if $k_x = k_y = 0$ the region is either the entire compl;ex plane (if $m_x > 0$) or the empty set.